# How can i convert date in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

My Grail application' list view has following date format from database:
 **2012-01-18 14:29:19 EST**

I am using

```
<g:datePicker name="myDate" value="${new Date().format("dd MM,yyyy")}"/>
```

and in controller:

```
def c  = abc.createCriteria()
    def x =  c.list{
            eq("name",params.wfName)
            eq("create_date",params.myDate)
    }
```

but the list x has nothing inside and return nothing.While i search only but wfName it works perfectly. params.myDate also has date value.

Can anyone please give a point?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because the "date" being passed in is a string.  Your criteria is looking for an actual date.

You don't specify what version of Grails you are using, but if it's Grails 2.0, they've added methods to params to make the conversion easier:

```
eq('create_date', params.date('myDate', 'dd MM,yyy'))
```

[Check out this article by mrhaki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/01/grails-goodness-date-request-parameter.html) fore more examples.

For older versions of Grails, you'll have to convert it yourself, using [Date.parse(params.myDate, "<< format >>")](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Since Grails 1.2 accessing `params.myDate` will automatically get you a Date object. If you're not using Grails 1.2 or higher, you'll need to manually create a Date object from the params.

I think the Date you are getting from your datePicker has too much precision to return anything in your query. Try changing your criteria to `lt("create_date", params.myDate)` to see if you can get any values returned. Also try `params.myDate.clearTime()` to just leave you with the date.

Comment: What if you create a new Date() and use that in the criteria?

Comment: dont get you. I am new to grails. Explain me with syntax.

Comment: `lt('create_date', new Date())`

Comment: If i create new date then how could it pass params.myDate from datepicker?

Comment: I just want you to try using a `new Date()` in the criteria to see if you can get results.

Answer (score 0):

i have the lates verion of grails but what about other methods of conversion